# How to get the title using BeautifulSoup and requests on python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So i want to get all the medicines information from this link : [Medicine List Link](https://www.klikdokter.com/obat)

I'm using BeautifulSoup4 and the requests, but I'm confused cause all the medicines use href, can anyone explain and help me how can I take all the information of the medicines?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.klikdokter.com/obat'

r = requests.get(url)
request = r.content


soup = BeautifulSoup(request, 'html.parser')

title = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class':''})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pp

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0'
}


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    goal = [x.text for x in soup.select(
        'a[class$=section__item-link]')]
    pp(goal)


main('https://www.klikdokter.com/obat')
```

Output:

```
['Abajos',
 'Abate',
 'Abbotic',
 'Abc Menthol Cone',
 'Abdelyn',
 'Abetens',
 'Abilify',
 'Abixa',
 'Abixim',
 'Abu Ali',
 'Ab Vask',
 'Acai Plus',
 'Acarbose',
 'Acdat',
 'Acelaxon',
 'Ace Maxs',
 'Acepress',
 'Acetensa',
 'Acetin',
 'Acetram',
 'Baby Care',
 'Baby Cough',
 'Babygesic',
 'Bacbutol',
 'Bacitracin-polymyxin B',
 'Bactesyn',
 'Bactigras',
 'Bactirom',
 'Bactoderm',
 'Bactoprim Combi',
 'Bactraz',
 'Bactrim',
 'Bactrizol',
 'Bactroban',
 'Bainian Angong Wan',
 'Balance Madia Cold Ease',
 'Balance Madia Cool Down',
 'Balance Madia Feminine Health',
 'Balance Madia Good Night',
 'Baljitot',
 'C2fit',
 'Cabe Jawa Al Afiat',
 'Cabe Puyang',
 'Cabertis Kids',
 'Cado',
 'Caduet',
 'Cafmosol',
 'Cakar Ayam',
 'Cal-95',
 'Caladine',
 'Caladine Krim',
 'Calamed',
 'Calceo',
 'Calcianta',
 'Calcid',
 'Calcidin',
 'Calcido',
 'Calcifar',
 'Calcifar Plus',
 'Calciflavone',
 'Dacin',
 'Daduzi',
 'Da Huo Luo Wan',
 'Daily Health Hyper-t',
 'Daily Witts',
 'Daiticin',
 'Daivobet',
 'Daivonex',
 'Dakista',
 'Dakoles',
 'Daktarin',
 'Daktarin Diaper',
 'Daktazol',
 'Dalacin C',
 'Dalfarol',
 'Dalipid',
 'Damaben',
 'Damandel',
 'Damuvit',
 'Daneuron',
 'Eas Pfrimmer',
 'Eazycal',
 'Ecalta',
 'Echinacea',
 'Echinatur',
 'Eclid',
 'Eco Slim',
 'Ecosol',
 'Ecotrixon',
 'Ecron',
 'Edemag',
 'Edemin',
 'Ediva',
 'Ediva Pure',
 'Ediva Young',
 'Edopect',
 'Edorisan',
 'Edotin',
 'Efavirenz',
 'Efexor Xr',
 'Fagofit',
 'Faktu',
 'Falergi',
 'Falpro',
 'Famocid',
 'Famotidine',
 'Fapresor',
 'Farbion',
 'Farbivent',
 'Farelax',
 'Fargelin For Piles',
 'Fargetix',
 'Fargoxin',
 'Farhes',
 'Faridexon',
 'Farizol',
 'Farlev',
 'Farmabes',
 'Farmabex C',
 'Farmacrol Forte',
 'G 1708 Body',
 'Gabapentin',
 'Gabasant',
 'Gabaxa',
 'Gabbryl',
 'Gabesco',
 'Gabexal',
 'Gabiten',
 'Gadung Klingsir',
 'Gaforin',
 'Galdom',
 'Galepsi',
 'Galfit',
 'Galflux',
 'Galian Delima Putih',
 'Galian Parem',
 'Galian Singset',
 'Galian Singset Sidomuncul',
 'Galinu',
 'Gallergin',
 'H2 - Celery',
 'H2 Cherished Skin',
 'H2 Chia Seeds',
 'H2 - Cordyceps Militaris',
 'H2 - Curcella',
 'H2 Fair Skin',
 'H2 - Genetron',
 'H2 Green Lipped Mussel',
 'H2 - Hemorid',
 'H2 - Kakao Instant',
 'H2 Pure Skin',
 'H2 - Shark Liver Oil',
 'H2 - Tepung Kelapa',
 'H2 - Turmeric',
 'H2 - Zativa',
 'Haba Garlic Oil',
 'Habasauda Prima',
 'Habasyah Kapsul',
 'Habbalife Pro',
 'Habbasy Bin Afif',
 'Iafed',
 'Iberet Folic',
 'Iboe Kunyit Asam',
 'Ibrosic',
 'Ibuprofen',
 'Ichtiyol Zalf',
 'Ichtyol',
 'Iclofar',
 'Icobal',
 'Icunes',
 'Idaman',
 'Ideal ',
 'Idesar',
 'Idesar Gold',
 'Ifalmin',
 'Ifarsyl',
 'Ifen',
 'Ifibion',
 'Ifidex',
 'Ifison',
 'Jacki Kapsul',
 'Jadied Kids',
 'Jadied Masela',
 'Jagacok',
 'Jagalangset',
 'Jagalinu',
 'Jagamuk',
 'Jagangin',
 'Jaganita',
 'Jagapria',
 'Jagaranggi',
 'Jagasma',
 'Jagatung',
 'Jagawas',
 'Jagotonik',
 'Jakavi',
 'Jakeni',
 'Jamasi',
 'Jameela G',
 'Jamieson B Complex',
 'Kabiroc',
 'Kabiven Peripheral',
 'Kadiflam',
 'Kaditic',
 'Ka-en',
 'Ka-en 1b',
 'Ka-en 3a',
 'Ka-en Mg3',
 'Kaflam',
 'Kal Alpha Lipoic Acid',
 'Kalbactam',
 'Kalbamin',
 'Kalbion',
 'Kalbiotic',
 'Kal Bone Defense',
 'Kalbutol',
 'Kal C 1000 Buffered',
 'Kalcinol N',
 'Kaldexon',
 'Kal E',
 'Laastro',
 'Laauratik',
 'Labalin',
 'Lac Activated Hgf',
 'Lacbon',
 'Lacedim',
 'Lacidofil',
 'Lacoldin',
 'Lacons',
 'Lacophen',
 'Lactaboost',
 'Lactacyd Baby Liquid',
 'Lactacyd Feminine Hygiene',
 'Lactacyd Feminine Hygiene',
 'Lactafar',
 'Lactakal',
 'Lactamam',
 'Lactamed',
 'Lactamor',
 'Lactasin',
 'M2j Kapsul',
 'Maag Gel',
 'Maagmeta Plus',
 'Mabthera',
 'Macef',
 'Maderic',
 'Madlexin',
 'Madmoi Slimming',
 'Madopar',
 'Madrox',
 'Madu Biomaag',
 'Madu Exofem',
 'Madu Exomen',
 'Madu Herbalovul (madu Herbal Ovul)',
 'Madu Jamkorat',
 'Madu Joybee',
 'Madu Makula',
 'Madu Myheart',
 'Madurasa',
 'Madurat',
 'N-ace',
 'Nacl 0,9%',
 'Nacoflar',
 'Nadifen',
 'Nado Langsing',
 'Naia Slimming',
 'Nairet',
 'Naletal',
 'Nalgestan',
 'Nalitik',
 'Naloxone',
 'Nanobet',
 'Nanobronch',
 'Nanogin',
 'Nanogurah',
 'Nanokoles',
 'Nanoman',
 'Nanoosteo',
 'Nanoremat',
 'Nanotens',
 'Oa Forte',
 'Oa Plus',
 'Obahama',
 'Obajan',
 'Obamig',
 'Obapa',
 'Obasa',
 'Obasma',
 'Obasma',
 'Obat Batuk Ibu Dan Anak',
 'Obat Batuk Madu Cap Kaki Tiga',
 'Obat Gosok Lo Siauw Gok',
 'Obat Gosok Shangshi Yao Gin',
 'Obatine',
 'Obdhamin',
 'Obeslim',
 'Obh Combi Anak Batuk Plus Flu',
 'Obh Combi Batuk Berdahak',
 'Obh Combi Batuk Plus Flu',
 'Obh Dryl',
 'Pabanox',
 'Pacdin Cough',
 'Pacdin Vitcur',
 'Pacego',
 'Pacekap',
 'Pacekap Diabest',
 'Pacekap Hi-ric',
 'Pacekap Kolest',
 'Pacetik',
 'Paclitaxel',
 'Padolin',
 'Paincare Force',
 'Paitan Resik',
 'Palenox',
 'Palentin',
 'Palest',
 'Palonosetron',
 'Paloxi',
 'Pamol',
 'Panadol',
 'Q10-ds',
 'Q 10 Plus',
 'Q-cef',
 'Qemofit',
 'Qianliexin',
 'Qian-shi',
 'Qi Gu Jiao Nang',
 'Qi Ju Di Huang Wan',
 'Qing Liang Cha',
 'Qing Yin Wan',
 'Qinox',
 'Qi Zao Ke Li',
 'Qlaira',
 'Q-lor',
 'Q Max',
 'Qnc Gamat',
 'Qn Clonk',
 'Q-pin',
 'Q-ten',
 'Quacefon',
 'Racef',
 'Radiker',
 'Radin',
 'Radivit',
 'Radol',
 'Rafacort',
 'Rahistin',
 'Raivas',
 'Ramabion',
 'Ramaflu',
 'Ramagesic',
 'Ramahist',
 'Ramaneuron',
 'Ramicort',
 'Ramipril',
 'Ramolit',
 'Ramoxyl',
 'Ranacid Forte',
 'Ranicho',
 'Ranifin',
 'S26',
 'Sabdo Candik Ayu',
 'Sabdo Kido',
 'Sabdo Lancar Haid',
 'Sabdo Majakani',
 'Sabdo Sari Asih',
 'Sabdo Sari Rapet',
 'Sabdo Sepet Wangi',
 'Safe Care',
 'Safetin',
 'Safflower Tablet',
 'Sagabumin',
 'Sagalon',
 'Sagestam',
 'Sahne Skin Nutrition',
 'Saizen',
 'Sakada',
 'Sakatonik Abc',
 'Sakatonik Liver',
 'Salakinase Plus',
 'T4bmax',
 'Tabas',
 'Tablet Delniu',
 'Tablet New Prourat',
 'Taburia Saf',
 'Taceral',
 'Taflotan',
 'Tagyt',
 'Takana',
 'Takelin',
 'Talion',
 'Tamacap',
 'Tamakalk',
 'Tamanopan',
 'Tamcocin',
 'Tamezole',
 'Tamiflu',
 'Tamofen',
 'Tamoliv',
 'Tamsulosin',
 'Ubesco',
 'Ubiforce',
 'Ubi Q',
 'Ubiquinol',
 'Ubiquinol - Coq10',
 'Uc-flex',
 'Ulbamed',
 'Ulcan',
 'Ulcera',
 'Ulceranin',
 'Ulcerid',
 'Ulcron',
 'Ulcumaag',
 'Ulcusan',
 'Ulmo',
 'Ulpraz',
 'Ulsafate',
 'Ulsicral',
 'Ulsidex',
 'Ulsikur',
 'Vaclo',
 'Vactiv',
 'Vadazol',
 'Vadrol',
 'Vagistin',
 'Vagizol',
 'Vaksin Adacel',
 'Vaksin Bcg Kering',
 'Vaksin Bioads',
 'Vaksin Boostrix',
 'Vaksin Campak Kering',
 'Vaksin Fluquadri',
 'Vaksin Gardasil',
 'Vaksin Infanrix',
 'Vaksin Infanrix-ipv+hib',
 'Vaksin Jerap Td Bio',
 'Vaksin Priorix',
 'Vaksin Tetanus Toxoid',
 'Vaksin Varivax',
 'Valaciclovir',
 'Waisan',
 'Walatra Hatma',
 'Walatra Hexabumin',
 'Walatra Jelly Gamat',
 'Walatra Zedoril 7',
 'Wal-chii',
 'Waluya',
 'Wang Lau Chik',
 'Warfarin',
 'Wasifit',
 'Wasilloss',
 'Wasiri',
 'Wasirungu',
 'Weikangling Jiaonang',
 'Weilos',
 'Weitong Pian',
 'Wellkid',
 'Wellman',
 'Wellness Antiox Formula',
 'Wellness Bee Complete',
 'X3man',
 'Xalacom',
 'Xalatan',
 'Xalkori',
 'Xanax Xr',
 'Xanda',
 'Xantia',
 'Xantonin',
 'Xanturic',
 'Xanvit',
 'Xarelto',
 'Xatral Xl',
 'X-cam',
 'Xeloda',
 'Xenical',
 'Xenifar',
 'Xenocy',
 'Xepabion',
 'Xepafen',
 'Xepalium',
 'Yafix',
 'Yaforan',
 'Yakoli',
 'Yalone',
 'Yao Tong Pian',
 'Yaricef',
 'Yaridon',
 'Yarizine',
 'Yasmin',
 'Yaz',
 'Yefamox',
 'Yekadine',
 'Yekadryl Expectorant',
 'Yekadryl Extra',
 'Yekaflu',
 'Yekamulvita',
 'Yekaneuron',
 'Yekapons',
 'Yekaprim',
 'Yekaradin',
 'Zac',
 'Zacoldine',
 'Zaditen',
 'Zaitunfit',
 'Zaitun Hikmah Oil',
 'Zaitun Medina',
 'Zaldiar',
 'Zambuk',
 'Zamel',
 'Zamel Drop',
 'Zamor',
 'Zand-q Digest',
 'Zanic',
 'Zanidip',
 'Zantifar',
 'Zarom',
 'Zatrimet',
 'Zecamex',
 'Zecaneuron Forte',
 'Zedoariplus',
 '2m-mata',
 '3tc',
 '3tc-hbv']
```

Comment: what should i do if i need the information of each medicines as well? can I make it as a table?

Comment: That's against the community terms, You've received an answer according to the question being asked. please check [ask]